# Is it possible to use include file as variable within include file

Tags: smarty

Is it possible to use an include file call as a variable within an include file call?

Below is an example of what I need:

```
{include file="data/data.inc.tpl" opts="{include file="data/dataset.inc.tpl"}"}
```

So the information from `dataset.inc.tpl` is used as a variable to display various options from `data.inc.tpl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can capture the contents of the include in a variable:

```
{capture name=dataset}
   {include file="data/dataset.inc.tpl"}
{/capture}

{include file="data/data.inc.tpl" opts=$smarty.capture.dataset}
```

or pass the file name to be included

```
{include file="data/data.inc.tpl" opts='data/dataset.inc.tpl'}
```

and then in data.inc.tpl...

```
{capture name=dataset}
   {include $opts}
{/capture}
```